# Could reverting to my old site bring back old SEO rankings?

Tags: seo, google-ranking

Suppose I have s website that shows on 2nd Google page and I want to redesign it. What elements should I keep unchanged so that the ranking is not effected?

If the ranking does go down and I decide to re-upload the old files, will the rank just return to what it had been?

Answer (score 1):

There are some thing that you must not change as :

1. (`<title>`) tag of the pages,
2. Meta Tags like meta keywords and meta description (if any)
3. Heading tags (`<h1><h2>...<h6>`),
4. Content of the page,
5. Url structure of the page
6. Google verification code

Except these you can do any changes and Google won't take you down in ranking.

Comment: Welcome on Pro Webmasters! For your information, meta keywords is not taken into account by Google anymore (and for many years now).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your Google rankings when redesigning your page you should maintain the following as much as possible:

- Page title (`<title>`)
- The main content text that is used on the page
- The link structure (which pages link to it and which ones it links to)
- The URL

I have done many page redesigns that change the layout, colors, styles, and images without hurting SEO rankings.  It is even possible to make some changes to the items that I listed without hurting your rankings, but the more changes that you make, the riskier it becomes.

Unfortunately, if your Google rankings do fall, it has been my experience that reverting does not cause your rankings to come back quickly.    Google seems to remember coding mistakes and ill thought out changes.  Rankings may suffer, even after correcting the problems.

Google may do this for a couple reasons:

- Your reputation suffers in their eyes when your site changes for the worse.   Changing it back doesn't help your reputation much because you now have a reputation for screwing up.
- Positive changes may take a while to increase rankings.  Google may do to make SEO experiments harder to conduct.   They don't like webmasters to know which changes make them rank better.   Delaying good rankings after changes are made make clarity on which changes matter harder to infer.

Comment: `alt=""` texts for non decorative images also shouldn't be changed.